Resilience4j different retryAttempts on different exceptions
I want to retry different number of times on different exceptions. Is it possible with resilience4j retry with yaml or custom configuration.
I tried searching for their documentation and other blogs but did not find any info.
For example, I want to retry 1 time for TokenException and 3 times for serverRetryableException.
resilience4j.retry:
  configs:
    default:
      maxRetryAttempts: 3
      waitDuration: 2000
      retryExceptions:
        - com.lulu.social.exception.TokenException
        - com.lulu.social.exception.ServerRetryableException

Note: I am using resilienc4j 2.1.0 with spring boot 2.7.9
